# Wifi not working after using ethernet cable and virtualized linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, ethernet

Okay, so I installed l-ubuntu on virtual box (which is installed on windows 7-64 bit) and then on vmware player successfully to learn some bash programming. Then, I connected my computer to the internet with an ethernet cable. When I disconnect the ethernet cable, I lose my wifi connection on the guest OS, ie windows 7. But, I can connect using an ethernet cable. 
Now I have to sit near my wireless gateway :P

I noticed that this problem was solved when i uninstalled virtualbox. But, it happened with vmware player too. I tried using windows "troubleshooting", but it does not work.

How do I get out of this mess ? I need virtualized lubuntu badly and with a working wifi connection.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it. It was disabled, probably by windows host, in the "change adapter settings" menu of "network settings" in windows. Simple fix.

Steps -

Start > Control panel > Network and Internet > Network and sharing center >......

Or you could do all of the above steps in one step by clicking on the internet/wifi icon on your taskbar and then choosing "open network and sharing center".

From here, go to change adapter settings. Your wireless connection should be visible here. It will be disabled (red cross next to its icon). Right click it > enable.

Comment: Can you expand a bit, for people who may not be as tech savvy as yourself?

Comment: @CanadianLuke - lol. I am not so tech savvy. I was just plain lucky. Updating the answer now.

Comment: Looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

Bridged networking will not work over Wifi. It will work over physical LAN.  This is a limitation of one MAC per client in standard wifi client mode.

NAT will work over both.

Its my guess that you are using bridged networking, because it would work in exactly the manner you have described.

Comment: ok, but how do I fix it ? It was working before.

Comment: configure all of your guests to use NAT networking. Avoid bridged.

Comment: btw, i just fixed it. It was disabled, probably by windows host, in the connection adapter settings. simple fix.